# Ajax replace the value if exist the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am try to display new values in table means previous values also combined and displayed into new value.. i give submit without refreshing means new values only dispalyed.

i tried this code

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,                             
            type: "POST",
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType : "json",
            cache: false,            
            success: function(datass){ 
                var count=datass.length;
                for( i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
                    $('#indexedurl').append('<tr class="odd indexedurl"><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+datass[i].url+'</td><td>'+datass[i].status+'</td></tr>');
                }
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                 console.log(errorThrown);  
            }
```

can anyone know this concept please replay. Thank You :)

Comment: `append` does that!

Comment: yes...but my problem is if i give new values without refresh my page previous values also displayed into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can empty your table content before append the received data:

```
success: function(datass){ 
    var count=datass.length;
    for( i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
       $('#indexedurl').empty().append('<tr class="odd indexedurl"><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+datass[i].url+'</td><td>'+datass[i].status+'</td></tr>');
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks...but it displayed last rows only

Comment: i need entirely replace all the rows

Comment: If the rows are indexed somehow, you can try to add a data-id attribute in each tr row, and then compare with the new received, in order to update only the received ones

Answer (score 0):

before the append try this line 
$("#indexedurl").html("");

OR

$('#indexedurl').html('');

Here is my example

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="UOMDetailTable">
 <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>Serial</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Detail</th>
          <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
```

```
     <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here is ajax SuccessMethod

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log(data);
                var counter = 1;
                $("#UOMDetailTable tbody").html("");

   for (var i in data) 
           {
            var cli = data[i];
              $("#UOMDetailTable tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + counter + "</td>" + " <td>" + cli.Description + "</td>" + "   <td>" + cli.Detail + "</td>" + "<td></td></tr>");

                    counter += 1;
            }
  },
```